# How to access Magento 2 soap api from C#

Tags: magento2, soap, soap-api-v2

I would like to know (a sample code if it is not too much to ask for) how to talk to Magento 2's SOAP API from C# using **Webservice** (not service reference). With Magento 1.x versions I used something like

```
static MagentoWebService.MagentoService MyService = new MagentoWebService.MagentoService();

static string Login = MyService.login(Config.Login, Config.Password);
```

where as login being,

```
    public string login(string username, string apiKey) 
    {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("login", new object[] {
                    username,
                    apiKey});
        return ((string)(results[0]));
    }
```

How do I do the same/similar one with Magento 2. I have seen few example given in PHP. However, I am struggling to convert that in to C# or understand properly. Could someone please help with this.

So far in my new code I tried this:

```
catalogProductRepositoryV1Service productservice = new catalogProductRepositoryV1Service();
        CatalogProductRepositoryV1GetResponse response = new CatalogProductRepositoryV1GetResponse();
        CatalogProductRepositoryV1GetRequest request = new CatalogProductRepositoryV1GetRequest();
        request.sku = "WJ01";
        response = productservice.catalogProductRepositoryV1Get(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.result.id.ToString());
```

But it wont work, since I haven't logged in to the SOAP service yet.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make requests to Magento 2 web API using the following example in 2014 (before 2.0 release), but it should work now as well.

To run it, follow the steps:

1. Open Visual Studio C# 2010 Express
2. Create new console application project
3. In the project tree click on the project root to view context menu and select "Add Service Reference"
4. Set **address** to `http://<magento.host>/soap/default?wsdl&services=customerCustomerAccountServiceV1` **namespace** to `MagentoService`
5. Add example below to your project and update Access token field with actual value
6. Run the program, console will be opened and simple attribute values are displayed

C# console application example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ConsoleApplication1.MagentoService;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string accessToken = "9b8cpqlvrberc51o02nccmg82yyechxe";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            customerCustomerAccountServiceV1PortTypeClient customerApi = new customerCustomerAccountServiceV1PortTypeClient();
            CustomerCustomerAccountServiceV1GetCustomerRequest request = new CustomerCustomerAccountServiceV1GetCustomerRequest();
            request.customerId = 1;
            CustomerCustomerAccountServiceV1GetCustomerResponse response;
            try
            {
                /** Set authorization headers and sent a request */
                using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(customerApi.InnerChannel))
                {
                    var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                    httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

                    response = customerApi.customerCustomerAccountServiceV1GetCustomer(request);
                }

                CustomerV1DataCustomer customerData = response.result;
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Customer email is: {0}.", customerData.email);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Custom attributes:", customerData.email);
                foreach (FrameworkDataEavAttributeValue attribute in customerData.customAttributes)
                {
                    /** Cast object of generic type to its real type */
                    System.Xml.XmlNode[] value = (System.Xml.XmlNode[])attribute.value;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", attribute.attributeCode, value[0].Value);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            Console.In.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

This example uses Service reference (not Webservice), but still might be helpful to understand how to pass authentication headers.

Comment: Thanks for your time Alex :) I have it working using service reference. But for some reason (serialization error, i logged before) i would like to check with web reference too. With web reference there is no option i can see of to provide access token or creating http header.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add service references, here is a list of them broken down by magento type.  You'll have to disable soap security for them to work with c#.

```
https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=storeStoreRepositoryV1,storeGroupRepositoryV1,storeWebsiteRepositoryV1,storeStoreConfigManagerV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=directoryCurrencyInformationAcquirerV1,directoryCountryInformationAcquirerV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=backendModuleServiceV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=eavAttributeSetRepositoryV1,eavAttributeSetManagementV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=searchV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=customerGroupRepositoryV1,customerGroupManagementV1,customerCustomerGroupConfigV1,customerCustomerMetadataV1,customerAddressMetadataV1,customerCustomerRepositoryV1,customerAccountManagementV1,customerAddressRepositoryV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=cmsPageRepositoryV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=cmsBlockRepositoryV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1,catalogProductAttributeTypesListV1,catalogProductAttributeRepositoryV1,catalogCategoryAttributeRepositoryV1,catalogCategoryAttributeOptionManagementV1,catalogProductTypeListV1,catalogAttributeSetRepositoryV1,catalogAttributeSetManagementV1,catalogProductAttributeManagementV1,catalogProductAttributeGroupRepositoryV1,catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1,catalogProductMediaAttributeManagementV1,catalogProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementV1,catalogProductTierPriceManagementV1,catalogTierPriceStorageV1,catalogBasePriceStorageV1,catalogCostStorageV1,catalogSpecialPriceStorageV1,catalogCategoryRepositoryV1,catalogCategoryManagementV1,catalogCategoryListV1,catalogProductCustomOptionTypeListV1,catalogProductCustomOptionRepositoryV1,catalogProductLinkTypeListV1,catalogProductLinkManagementV1,catalogProductLinkRepositoryV1,catalogCategoryLinkManagementV1,catalogCategoryLinkRepositoryV1,catalogProductWebsiteLinkRepositoryV1,catalogProductRenderListV1,catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=quoteCartRepositoryV1,quoteCartManagementV1,quoteGuestCartRepositoryV1,quoteGuestCartManagementV1,quoteShippingMethodManagementV1,quoteShipmentEstimationV1,quoteGuestShippingMethodManagementV1,quoteGuestShipmentEstimationV1,quoteCartItemRepositoryV1,quoteGuestCartItemRepositoryV1,quotePaymentMethodManagementV1,quoteGuestPaymentMethodManagementV1,quoteBillingAddressManagementV1,quoteGuestBillingAddressManagementV1,quoteCouponManagementV1,quoteGuestCouponManagementV1,quoteCartTotalRepositoryV1,quoteGuestCartTotalManagementV1,quoteGuestCartTotalRepositoryV1,quoteCartTotalManagementV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1,salesOrderManagementV1,salesOrderAddressRepositoryV1,salesOrderItemRepositoryV1,salesInvoiceRepositoryV1,salesInvoiceManagementV1,salesInvoiceCommentRepositoryV1,salesRefundInvoiceV1,salesCreditmemoManagementV1,salesCreditmemoRepositoryV1,salesCreditmemoCommentRepositoryV1,salesRefundOrderV1,salesShipmentRepositoryV1,salesShipmentManagementV1,salesShipmentCommentRepositoryV1,salesShipmentTrackRepositoryV1,salesShipOrderV1,salesTransactionRepositoryV1,salesInvoiceOrderV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=checkoutGuestShippingInformationManagementV1,checkoutShippingInformationManagementV1,checkoutTotalsInformationManagementV1,checkoutGuestTotalsInformationManagementV1,checkoutGuestPaymentInformationManagementV1,checkoutPaymentInformationManagementV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=configurableProductLinkManagementV1,configurableProductConfigurableProductManagementV1,configurableProductOptionRepositoryV1


https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1,integrationCustomerTokenServiceV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=asynchronousOperationsBulkStatusV1,asynchronousOperationsOperationRepositoryV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=downloadableLinkRepositoryV1,downloadableSampleRepositoryV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=bundleProductLinkManagementV1,bundleProductOptionRepositoryV1,bundleProductOptionTypeListV1,bundleProductOptionManagementV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=giftMessageCartRepositoryV1,giftMessageItemRepositoryV1,giftMessageGuestCartRepositoryV1,giftMessageGuestItemRepositoryV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=analyticsLinkProviderV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=salesRuleRuleRepositoryV1,salesRuleCouponRepositoryV1,salesRuleCouponManagementV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=checkoutAgreementsCheckoutAgreementsRepositoryV1,checkoutAgreementsCheckoutAgreementsListV1

https://yourwebsite.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=taxTaxRateRepositoryV1,taxTaxRuleRepositoryV1,taxTaxClassRepositoryV1
```